# How to increment Map item in ES6 + flow?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I have

```
let accounts: Map<string, number> = new Map();
```

How can I can increment value by specific key?
Something like `accounts["key"]++`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you are only using string keys in your `Map`, and you’ve told Flow that is the case, you still have to use `Map#get()` and `Map#set()` to change values. There are no shortcuts for incrementing an integer.

```
let accounts: Map<string, number> = new Map();
accounts.set("an account", 0);
accounts.set("an account", accounts.get("an account") + 1);
console.log(accounts.get("an account"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to get the value and set it.

```
accounts.set("key", accounts.get("key") + 1);
```